# Should light be exported when rendered in a different engine?

Tags: export, light

My impression is the following (correct me if I am wrong):

Presumption: Models are used in a different engine (for example for a game) which renders light by itself.

Exporting light with blender would only produce glitches and bugs with another engine right?

Under what circumstances would it be useful to export blender light/light-sources?

Ultimately can I delete any lightsource in blender without hesitation if I know that it will be rendered by another engine?